# Drawing a dynamic shape in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitouch

I am trying to create a simple circle by subclassing the `UIView` which I am able to do. But now I want to do various operations over it, such as Rotate, Pan, Scale, etc by various touch events.

How can I do these?

Answer (score 0):

Just make custom object so u can get event for particular of.